# winrm or requests is not installed: cannot import name certs with installed pywinrm

Tags: python, windows, ansible, winrm

I'm trying to rollout directories, users and standard software over ansible on windows systems. To do so I've created a role which will handle that for me.
Now I've two environments: 1 dev environment with two Windows Server 2016 VM's and 1 QA environment with two Windows 2016 Server VM's.

The role is the same, only the vm's are others.

When I execute my role on the dev environment side everything works fine. All tasks for windows systems can be executed.

Here are my entries in dev host file for ansible:

```
[dev_win_servers]
dev_win_1 ansible_host=10.40.85.15 ansible_port=443 ansible_connection=winrm ansible_winrm_transport=ntlm ansible_user=Administrator ansible_password='{{ pw_dev_win_1 }}' ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore 
dev_win_2 ansible_host=10.40.85.16 ansible_port=443 ansible_connection=winrm ansible_winrm_transport=ntlm ansible_user=Administrator ansible_password='{{ pw_dev_win_2 }}' ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
```

When I execute the same role on qa systems I'm getting this error:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [eti_banksystem_ha2_win1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "winrm or requests is not installed: cannot import name certs"}
```

The hosts on QA network are quiet the same, only IP Address and server names are different:

```
[qa_win_servers]
qa_win_1 ansible_host=10.40.11.100 ansible_port=443 ansible_connection=winrm ansible_winrm_transport=ntlm ansible_user=Administrator ansible_password='{{ pw_qa_win_1 }}' ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
qa_win_2 ansible_host=10.40.11.101 ansible_port=443 ansible_connection=winrm ansible_winrm_transport=ntlm ansible_user=Administrator ansible_password='{{ pw_qu_win_2 }}' ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
```

On the windows VM's in dev and qa I've configured a winrm listener over https on port 443 with that command (example for one host):

```bsh
PS C:\Users\Administrator> winrm create winrm/config/Listener? Address=*+Transport=HTTPS '@{Hostname="eti-dcv-ha2-ap3"; CertificateThumbprint="C398C1C5857D5FDAAC791289439CB88FE9
0DE755"; Port="443"}'
```

The certificate is a local generated selfsigned cert which I've generated before with:

```bsh
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "qa_win_2" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

On my ansible servers in dev and uat all python packages installed via yum are the same and in same version. I've checked it over executing this on both ansible servers, put result in a text file and do a diff over it:

```sh
yum list | grep ^python | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort
```

Also pywinrm and requests is installed on both systems like this

```sh
fgi-dcv-depl1 root# yum list | grep winrm
python2-winrm.noarch                  0.3.0-1.el7              @epel.xc         
fgi-dcv-depl1 root# yum list | grep requests
python-requests.noarch                2.6.0-1.el7_1            @base.xcmonthly  
python2-requests_ntlm.noarch          1.1.0-1.el7              @epel.xc         
python-requests-kerberos.noarch       0.7.0-2.el7              epel.xc          
python-requests-toolbelt.noarch       0.8.0-1.el7              epel.xc          
python-txrequests.noarch              0.9.2-3.el7              epel.xc          
python2-requests.noarch               2.6.0-0.el7              epel.xc          
python2-requests-file.noarch          1.4.3-3.el7              epel.xc          
python2-requests-gssapi.noarch        1.0.1-1.el7              epel.xc          
python2-requests-mock.noarch          1.5.2-1.el7              epel.xc          
python2-requests-oauthlib.noarch      0.8.0-5.el7              base.xcmonthly   
python34-requests.noarch              2.12.5-3.el7             epel.xc          
python36-requests.noarch              2.12.5-3.el7             epel.xc          
fgi-dcv-depl1 root#
```

And over pip:

```
fgi-dcv-depl1 root# pip2.7 list | grep winrm
pywinrm                          0.3.0    
fgi-dcv-depl1 root# pip2.7 list | grep requests
requests                         2.19.1   
requests-ntlm                    1.1.0    
fgi-dcv-depl1 root#
```

As both systems are behind a firewall which will deny the access to the internet I'm not able to install anything over pip:

```sh
fgi-dcv-depl1 root# pip2.7 install --upgrade requests
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2a4c9bd6d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/requests/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2a4c9bd810>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/requests/
^COperation cancelled by user
fgi-dcv-depl1 root#
```

EDIT: I've found some ideas more to try out the winrm connection over python console. On my dev systems:

```py
fgi-dcv-appdeploysrv root# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 20 2019, 20:27:34) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import winrm
>>> s=winrm.Session('https://10.40.85.15:443',auth=('administrator','mypw'),transport='ntlm',server_cert_validation='ignore')
>>> r=s.run_cmd('ipconfig')
>>> print r.std_out

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.40.85.15
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.40.85.1

>>> quit()
```

On qa system the import of winrm doesn't work:

```py
fgi-dcv-depl1 root# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 20 2019, 20:27:34) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import winrm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from winrm.protocol import Protocol
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 11, in <module>
    from winrm.transport import Transport
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 15, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .exceptions import InvalidURL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/exceptions.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.exceptions import HTTPError as BaseHTTPError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 95, in load_module
    raise ImportError("No module named '%s'" % (name,))
ImportError: No module named 'requests.packages.urllib3'
>>> quit()
fgi-dcv-depl1 root#
```

Meybe the error is somewhere here?

Anybody who can help here?

Thanks and best regards,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, something seems to be strange with python-urllib3. YUM tells me, it was not installed

```
fgi-dcv-depl1 root# yum install python-urllib3
Loaded plugins: aliases, changelog, fastestmirror, tmprepo, verify, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-urllib3.noarch 0:1.10.2-5.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=======================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                                           Arch                                                                      Version                                                                           Repository                                                                         Size
=======================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 python-urllib3                                                                    noarch                                                                    1.10.2-5.el7                                                                      base.xcmonthly                                                                    102 k

Transaction Summary
=======================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 102 k
Installed size: 378 k
Is this ok [y/d/N]:
```

So I want to install the package:

```
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
python-urllib3-1.10.2-5.el7.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          | 102 kB  00:00:00     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : python-urllib3-1.10.2-5.el7.noarch                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1/1 
Error unpacking rpm package python-urllib3-1.10.2-5.el7.noarch
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/ssl_match_hostname: cpio: rename
  Verifying  : python-urllib3-1.10.2-5.el7.noarch                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1/1 

Failed:
  python-urllib3.noarch 0:1.10.2-5.el7                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

Complete!
fgi-dcv-depl1 root#
```

OK why that error? I've looked intop /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages and saw, that a directory urllib3 was there. I've moved it to /tmp, after that I was able to install python-urllib3 package and everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sudo pip uninstall urllib3
```

then try:

```
sudo yum install python-urllib3
```